# Querying MongoDB to return 5 most recent records (Mongoose framework)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to query my MongoDB to return the 5 most recent records. I have Mongoose as my framework and using Node.js as my server. I have the model here:

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var uGardenDataModel = new Schema({
temp: String,
humidity: String,
soilMoisture: String,
light: String,
timestamp: Date,
});
// Create model
var uGardenData = mongoose.model('UGarden', uGardenDataModel);
```

---

My function to query the DB is here:

```
function getChartData(res){
//uGardenData.find({},{sort: {_id:-1}},limit: 5, function(err, post){
    uGardenData.find({sort:{'timestamp': -1}},{limit: 5}, function(err, post){
    if(err){
        res.send({success: false});
        console.log('failed');
    } else {
        res.send({data:post,success:true});
        console.log('success');
    }
})
}
```

I believe I have the syntax for the query wrong. Once I make an HTTP request for the function using the browser's console I get:
data: Array(0), success: true

Looks like its not returning any data despite having records in the DB. 
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're calling `find` incorrectly. According to the manual, [`find`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#find_find) takes one mandatory parameter and 3 optional parameters. Sort and Limit are part of the [`options`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-setOptions) parameter, which is 3rd. So you need to still pass the first two, though empty.

Try the below call:

```
uGardenData.find({}, null, {sort:{'timestamp': -1},limit: 5}, function(err, post){
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks a million!